# Align Font awesome and text to left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I'm trying to align my icons and text to the left but it seems a little messy

my code is really simple:

```
<p class="text-muted mb-2 text-left">22/8 <i class="fa fa-calendar-alt fa-1x"></i>
<br>21:00 <i class="fa fa-clock fa-1x"></i>
<br>Herzeliya <i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt fa-1x"></i>
<br>Texy <i class="fa fa-home fa-1x"></i>
<br>
```

Can someone help me to align them straight left?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What does *"a little messy"* mean?...also, close the paragraph

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to set container widths for icons in accordance with the width of the widest.

```
<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <p class="text-muted mb-2 text-left">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar-alt fa-1x fa-custom-width mr-2"></i>22/8
                <br>
                <i class="fa fa-clock fa-1x fa-custom-width mr-2"></i>21:00
                <br>
                <i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt fa-1x fa-custom-width mr-2"></i>Herzeliya
                <br>
                <i class="fa fa-home fa-1x fa-custom-width mr-2"></i>Texy
                <br>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.fa-custom-width{
    width: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/GQAdPupsFU

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `fa-fw` class (included in Font Awesome)...

```
<p class="text-muted mb-2 text-left">
       <i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar-alt fa-1x"></i> 22/8
       <br><i class="fa fa-fw fa-clock fa-1x"></i> 21:00
       <br><i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker-alt fa-1x"></i> Herzeliya
       <br><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home fa-1x"></i> Texy
       <br>
</p>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/ouYds9p7kc